# How do you convert an array of strings into numbers... is the only way map()?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, ecmascript-6

I was able to figure out how to convert user input into an array of strings to an array of integers, but is `map` the only way or could I have used `parseInt` in some other way?

```js
const myArray = [];
const addData = function() {
  let inputData = document.getElementById('user_input');
  myArray.push(inputData.value);
  console.log(myArray.map(Number));
}
document.getElementById('myBtn').addEventListener('click', addData);
```

```html
<input type="number" id="user_input">
<button type="button" id="myBtn">Click to store</button>
```

I used: `myArray.map(Number)`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual way is to call `parseInt()` on the input value before using it. This way you don't have to keep parsing everything in the array.

```js
const myArray = [];
const addData = function() {
  let inputData = document.getElementById('user_input');
  myArray.push(parseInt(inputData.value));
  console.log(myArray);
}
document.getElementById('myBtn').addEventListener('click', addData);
```

```html
<input type="number" id="user_input">
<button type="button" id="myBtn">Click to store</button>
```